# Как задать тип переменной в роутере (Ошибка: [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "id". Expected Number, got String.)

Tags: vue.js

Я пытаюсь получить значение переменную `id` из URL.

В роутере в `index.js` я прописал следующий код:

```js
{   path: '/word/:id',
    name: 'word',   
    component: Word,
    props: true,
},
```

Код компонента:

```html
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
             id: Number,
        },
        created() {
             this.routeChanged();
        },
        watch: {
            'id': 'routeChanged',
        },
        methods: {
            routeChanged () {
                console.log(this.id);
            },
        },
    };
</script>
```

Но в консоли при открытии страницы я получаю предупреждение:

> [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "id". Expected Number, got String.

Как мне исправить мой код?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Invalid prop type from router params, expected Number got String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51418072/5752652) от участника  [@abu abu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5043301/abu-abu).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51418072

Answer (score 1):

Это подходящий случай для передачи свойств в роутер при помощий [функции](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F):

> Вы можете создать функцию, которая вернёт объект с входными
>   параметрами. Это позволяет вам приводить параметры к другим типам,
>   комбинировать статические значения с значениями из маршрута, и т.д.

В вашем случае вместо определения опциий роутера при помощи `props: true`, вам необходимо передавать функцию в `props`:

```js
routes = [{
  path: '/word/:id',
  component: Word,
  props: castRouteParams
}];

function castRouteParams(route) {
  return {
    id: Number(route.params.id),
  };
}
```

Образец: https://codesandbox.io/s/8kyyw9w26l (кликните на ссылку "Go to Test/3")

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа https://stackoverflow.com/a/51418611/5752652 от участника  [@ghybs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5108796/ghybs).</sub>